# Google Cloud Storage REST API takes too much time when uploading a file

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to upload a file through Google Cloud Storage REST API. It works fine, but the task takes too much time, I think. The last test I did was uploading a 171KB sized picture, and the task was working for 71 seconds. (my upload connection is able to upload 251KB/s, by an online speed test).

The code I am executing is almost equal as the one placed in [storage-cmdline-sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/storage-cmdline-sample). The only thing I modified was the mediaContent to upload (instead the RandomDataBlockInputStream, I'm trying to upload a FileInputStream with the picture).

I don't know if it's normal, but doesn't look like that. What could be the thing am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please change the log level (more details [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/HTTP#Logging)) and attach the log output? It seems weird, it shouldn't take about 71 seconds to upload a 171KB file.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer.

The log generated was this: http://pastebin.com/MAAGXCag

The method I'm launching, is this one: http://pastebin.com/sCkMnvd5

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did use the [**JetS3t java toolkit**](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html) and the file was uploaded in 5 seconds only.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

A new issue was opened in our issue tracker, you can find it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=799&thanks=799&ts=1371214804). Feel free to add more information on it, we will try to get into it ASAP.